# React-native unable to resolve module on importing a js file

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, import

I am getting this error whenever I try to import a new js page. I am fairly new to react-native so this might be an easy error to fix or it might be a bug on their side at the moment, I am not sure. 
This is my import line -> 
    `import Home from 'Home';`
Both files are in the same directory. The error I get is it says

> unable to resolve module 'Home' from 'path/App.js' : Module does not exist in the module map'.

Now what confuses me is that the path on the error is App.js when I am trying to specify a file called Home.js.

Comment: Try adding a relative path: `import Home from './Home';`

Comment: That seems to solve the issue, thanks! I did attempt that earlier, however you have to exit out of the terminal and the ios simulator for it reset which I did not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a relative import like this:

```
import Home from './Home';
```

Of course, that is assuming the Home component is in the same level as your App component and that you exported it as the default export:

```
export default Home
```

Comment: So far, it seems to work without the export default Home line. What is its purpose?